# Is this formula for the harmonic numbers true?

Tags: limits, indefinite-integrals, harmonic-numbers

Is this formula for the harmonic numbers true?

$$H_n = \lim_{s\to 0} \, \int \frac{(s+1)^{(-n-1)}+s-1}{s} \, ds$$

Mathematica:

```
Clear[n, s]
Monitor[Table[
  Limit[Integrate[((s + 1)^(-n - 1) + s - 1)/s, s], s -> 0], {n, 1, 
   12}], n]
Differences[%]
```

Comment: What are the limits of integration?

Comment: I think it is $s$ which is a real number.

Comment: Any ways integrate with respect to $s$ first, then take the limit.

Comment: Integrate with respect to $s$ over what range? As is this doesn't actually make sense, because there's a constant of integration in an indefinite integral.

Comment: What is a range? Mathematica did this integration that I copied to latex, and pasted here.

Comment: I think what you actually mean is $\lim_{t \to 0} \int_a^t \frac{(s+1)^{-n-1} + s -1}{s} ds$, where $a$ is some constant that you haven't told us (my guess would be $0$). In the formula above the integral is over the range $[a,t]$.

Comment: Wait I will shut down Mathematica and run the code again.

Comment: I got the same answer again. The sequence of Harmonic numbers.

Comment: That doesn't actually make any sense with an indefinite integral, you're implicitly assuming that the constant of integration is $0$, which means that you are fixing either the lower or upper limit at some value. If you want to be precise you should consider what I wrote above.

Comment: @Ian: I think it would be reasonable to take the indefinite integral and ask if there is any constant that can be chosen that makes the equality hold for all $n$.

Comment: Yes, the formula is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I claim that

$$\frac{1}{(s+1)^n s} = \frac{1}{s} - \sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{1}{(s+1)^j}.$$

Let us prove this by induction. If $n=1$ then one may check that

$$\frac{1}{s (s+1)} = \frac{1}{s} - \frac{1}{s+1}$$

as desired. Now assume the statement is true for $n=k$. Using the inductive hypothesis we get

$$\frac{1}{(s+1)^{k+1} s} = \frac{\frac{1}{(s+1)^k s}}{s+1} = \frac{1}{s (s+1)} - \sum_{j=2}^{k+1} \frac{1}{(s+1)^j}.$$

Performing the same decomposition again gives

$$\frac{1}{(s+1)^{k+1} s} = \frac{1}{s} - \sum_{j=1}^{k+1} \frac{1}{(s+1)^j}$$

as desired.

Using the claim, we have

$$\frac{1}{(s+1)^{n+1} s} + 1 - \frac{1}{s} = 1 - \sum_{j=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{(s+1)^j}$$

Now for the original problem we have

$$\int \frac{1}{(s+1)^n s} + 1 - \frac{1}{s} ds = s - \ln(s+1) + \sum_{j=2}^{n+1} \frac{1}{(j-1) (s+1)^{j-1}} + C$$

so the limit is

$$\sum_{j=2}^{n+1} \frac{1}{j-1} + C = H_n + C$$

Note that the second $s$ in the numerator is in some sense superfluous, since the result of the limit is the same with or without it.